# Details from the db not passed on to html Django template

Tags: django

I am creating a blog site. The DB do have blog posts which is verified from the blog list page and also from the admin section. On clicking on the heading on the blog list page, the actual  blog post page should load, which does, however the blog details like the title and content doesn't appear on the blog post page.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ModelBlog(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body        = models.TextField()
    slug        = models.SlugField()
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mod_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumb       = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:270] + '...'
```

views.py (the second function is associated with the blog post page)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ModelBlog
from django.http import HttpResponse


def function_blog_list(request):
    var_blog = ModelBlog.objects.all().order_by('pub_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/blog-list.html', { 'prop_blog':var_blog })

def function_blog_post(request, slug):
    inst_post = ModelBlog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/blog-post.html', { 'prop_blogpost':inst_post })
```

HTML template (blog/blog-post.html)

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ inst_post.title }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog-post.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>{{ inst_post.title }}</h1>
      <p>Published on: {{ inst_post.pub_date }}</p>
      <p>Written by: {{ inst_post.author }}</p>
      <p>{{ inst_post.body }}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page loads and the static text inside `<p>` tag appears but not the blog details. Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using wrong variable names, instead of doing prop_blogpost.pub_date
you are doing  inst_post.pub_date which is wrong

Answer (score 4):

change template code to

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ prop_blogpost.title }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog-post.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>{{ prop_blogpost.title }}</h1>
      <p>Published on: {{ prop_blogpost.pub_date }}</p>
      <p>Written by: {{ prop_blogpost.author }}</p>
      <p>{{ prop_blogpost.body }}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

prop_blogpost is the key value is inst_post